# Does direct interparticle action imply advanced inertial forces?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, electromagnetism, special-relativity, lienard-wiechert

In his [Nobel lecture](https://www.nobelprize.org/prizes/physics/1965/feynman/lecture/) Richard Feynman states that by varying the Schwarzschild-Tetrode-Fokker direct interparticle action
$$A=-\sum_i m_i\int\big(\mathbf{\dot X_i}\cdot\mathbf{\dot X_i}\big)^{1/2}d\alpha_i+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i\ne j}e_ie_j\iint\delta(I_{ij}^2)\ \mathbf{\dot X_i}\cdot\mathbf{\dot X_j}\ d\alpha_i\ d\alpha_j\tag{1}$$
where
$$I_{ij}^2=\big[\mathbf{X_i}(\alpha_i)-\mathbf{X_j}(\alpha_j)\big]\cdot\big[\mathbf{X_i}(\alpha_i)-\mathbf{X_j}(\alpha_j)\big]$$
one can reproduce classical electrodynamics without using the concept of the electromagnetic field.

In their paper [Classical Electrodynamics in Terms of Direct Interparticle Action](https://cds.cern.ch/record/1062647/files/RevModPhys.21.425.pdf) John Wheeler and Richard Feynman showed in the section Action and Reaction on pages 429-430 that the energy-momentum transferred by retarded forces from particle $i$ to particle $j$ along a null worldline connecting them is equal and opposite to the energy-momentum transferred by advanced forces from particle $j$ back to particle $i$ along the same null worldline. Therefore they had discovered a Lorentz covariant generalization of Newton's principle of action and reaction.

Following the [Feynman Lectures vol.1 ch. 28 section 28-2](https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/I_28.html) I imagine two stationary particles with charges $e_1$ and $e_2$ separated by a large distance $r$ so that only the radiative electromagnetic forces, which decay as $1/r$, are relevant.

Let us suppose that I apply a contact force to particle $1$ at time $t$ that gives it an acceleration $\mathbf{a}(t)$ perpendicular to the line joining the two particles.

The retarded electromagnetic force received by particle $2$ at time $t+r/c$, having been emitted by particle $1$ at time $t$, is given by

$$\mathbf{F^{21}}(t+r/c)=\frac{-e_1 e_2}{4\pi\epsilon_0 c^2r}\mathbf{a}(t)\tag{2}$$

For simplicity let us suppose that the mass of particle $2$ is very large so that it hardly accelerates at all and therefore does not produce a retarded force back on particle $1$.

However if the direct interparticle action $(1)$ is a correct description of Nature then there should be an advanced reaction force back on particle $1$ at time $t$, emitted by particle $2$ at time $t+r/c$, given by

$$\mathbf{F^{12}}(t)=\frac{e_1 e_2}{4\pi\epsilon_0 c^2r}\mathbf{a}(t)\tag{2}$$

As this back reaction force is proportional to the acceleration then it will manifest itself as an apparent change in the inertia of particle $1$, $\Delta m_1$, given by

$$\Delta m_1=\frac{e_1 e_2}{4\pi\epsilon_0 c^2r}\tag{3}$$

This apparent change in inertia of particle $1$ should be detectable. Has any such effect been measured?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Feynman et. al. are in Ref. 1 deriving  a relativistic generalization of Newton's 3rd law in a closed system of point charges. However OP's momentary contact force to particle 1 constitutes an external force unless it is explained via say a 3rd point charge of the system, so OP's 2-particle scenario is at best an incomplete description.

Below we sketch a derivation of the interesting non-local direct interparticle action used by [Wheeler & Feynman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheeler%E2%80%93Feynman_absorber_theory), which goes back to Schwarzschild, Tetrode & Fokker.

1. We start we with the Maxwell Lagrangian density$^1$
   $$ \begin{align}{\cal L}_0
   ~~~~=~~~~& -\frac{1}{4} F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu}-\frac{\chi^2}{2\xi}\cr 
   ~\stackrel{\text{int. by parts}}{\sim}&~\frac{1}{2}A_{\mu}\Box A^{\mu}, \end{align}\tag{1}$$
   with [Lorenz gauge condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorenz_gauge_condition) $\chi=d_{\mu}A^{\mu}$ in [Feynman gauge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauge_fixing#R%CE%BE_gauges) $\xi=1$.
2. We next add sources
   $$ {\cal L}~=~{\cal L}_0 + A_{\mu}J^{\mu} \tag{2}$$
   in the form of point charges
   $$\begin{align} J^{\mu}(x) ~=~&\sum_i e_i \int\!d\lambda_i~\dot{x}_i^{\mu} \delta^4(x-x_i), \cr
   \dot{x}_i^{\mu}~\equiv~&\frac{dx_i^{\mu}}{d\lambda_i},
   \end{align} \tag{3}$$
   which satisfy the continuity equation $d_{\mu} J^{\mu}=0$. Here $\lambda^i$ is a world-line (WL) parameter for the $i$th point charge.
3. The [EL equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation) are $\Box A^{\mu}\approx-J^{\mu}$, with solutions
   $$\begin{align} A^{\mu}(x)~\approx~& \int \! d^4y~G_F(x-y) J^{\mu}(y)\cr
   ~=~&\sum_i e_i \int\!d\lambda_i~\dot{x}_i^{\mu} ~G_F(x-x_i), \end{align}\tag{4}$$
   where the [Feynman Greens function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagator) is
   $$\begin{align} 4\pi G_F(x)~=~ &\delta(x^2)~=~\frac{1}{2r}\sum_{\pm}\delta(t\pm r), \cr
    r~=~&\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}, \cr
    \Box G_F(x) ~=~&-\delta^4(x),\end{align}\tag{5}$$
   cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/614754/2451) Phys.SE post.
   This instills a symmetry between retarded and advanced propagations, and will lead to a relativistic generalization of Newton's 3rd law, cf. Ref. 1.
4. We add kinetic terms for the point charges
   $$ \begin{align}S_i~=~&\int d\lambda_i ~L_i, \cr
    L_i~=~& -m_i\sqrt{-\dot{x}_i^2}. \end{align}\tag{6}$$
   Note that the formulation is WL reparametrization invariant.
5. The full E&M action reads
   $$ S~=~\underbrace{\sum_i S_i}_{\text{matter}}+\underbrace{\int\! d^4x~{\cal L}}_{\text{fields + interactions}}.  \tag{7}$$
   The EL equation for the $i$th point charge is the relativistic Newton's 2nd law with the Lorentz force
   $$ \dot{p}_{i,\mu}~\approx~e_iF_{\mu\nu}(x_i)\dot{x}_i^{\nu}.\tag{8} $$
6. If we integrate out the $A_{\mu}$-field in the action (7) we get the non-local direct interparticle action
   of Schwarzschild, Tetrode & Fokker:
   $$\begin{align} S~\stackrel{A}{\longrightarrow}~&\sum_i S_i+\frac{1}{2}\int d^4x\int d^4y  ~J_{\mu}(x) G_F(x-y)J^{\mu}(y) \cr 
   ~=~&\sum_i S_i+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i\neq j} e_i e_j \int\!d\lambda_i~\int\!d\lambda_j~ \dot{x}_i\cdot \dot{x}_j~G_F(x_i-x_j) ,\end{align}\tag{9} $$
   where we have discarded the singular self-interaction terms in the double-sum of eq. (9).

References:

1. J.A. Wheeler & R.P. Feynman, *Classical Electrodynamics in Terms of Direct Interparticle Action,* [Rev. Mod. Phys. 21 (1949) 425](https://doi.org/10.1103/RevModPhys.21.425) ([PDF](https://cds.cern.ch/record/1062647/files/RevModPhys.21.425.pdf)).

--

$^1$ We use the Minkowski sign convention $(-,+,+,+)$ (which agrees with Ref. 1) and put $c=1$.

Comment: Very informative reply - thanks!

Comment: @John Eastmond: Thanks for an interesting question!

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/574207/2451