# Light in action-at-a-distance formulation of Electromagnetism

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, non-locality

If it is possible to use [Jefimenko's equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jefimenko%27s_equations) to formulate Electromagnetism as a non-instantaneous action-at-a-distance theory, what would electromagnetic radiation be in such a theory? Would it be a particle, a wave, neither? If light does not travel from an object to my eye, then how do I see that object? When we use radio waves for communication, can it be imagined as some kind of delayed teleportation of information?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/547254/2451

Answer (score 0):

Maxwell equations are sufficient even to explain light waves. I ask the questioner to assume the followings (for which a basic theory may be found in a book entitled “Planets and electromagnetic waves”).  The followings are based on mathematical interpretations for solutions of Maxwell equations.
(1)  If current exceeds some limit (depending on source of production), then magnetic field waves are produced.  These waves are called in general radio waves.
(2)  If voltage exceeds some limit (depending on source of production), then electric field waves are produced.  These waves are called in general light waves.
(3)  If current exceeds the corresponding limit and the voltage also exceeds the corresponding limit then both magnetic field waves and electric field waves exist separately; not in combined form (that is, not as everyone gives a figure for em waves with two component waves).
A peculiar situation for (3) is the Hertz’s experiment.  Both light waves (rays) and radio waves may be imagined in the same way for understanding purpose. Light rays are electric field waves.  Radio waves are magnetic field waves.  Wavelengths of light rays are less than or equal to 1.06 mm (approximately), and wavelengths of radio waves are greater than or equal to 1.06 mm.  We see an object when it emits some light ray or it reflects some light ray.