# Effective Lagrangian from Yukawa interaction

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, path-integral, effective-field-theory

I learned recently how to compute the basic generating functionals.  My next goal is to understand how I can use them to compute effective interactions. I started with the Yukawa interaction  because it is quadratic and, a priori, exactly solvable. On the other hand, the examples in books and lecture notes are in the great majority  based on  non-exactly solvable theories, like $\phi ^4$ theory ( e.g. https://arxiv.org/abs/2006.16285).

As Yukawa is quadratic I am performing the functional integration over the bosonic field and then obtaining  something  I imagine to be the effective potential. On the other hand, it is quite common to see books dealing with this kind of problem with the *steepest descent approximation* (I did not study this topic yet).  I am afraid to be forgetting something important by just doing the integration.

Here is what I did.
The Lagrangian of the full theory is given by

$$\mathcal{L} = \mathcal{L}_{\psi}  + \frac{1}{2} (\partial_\mu \phi)(\partial^\mu \phi) - \frac{1}{2}  m^2 \phi^2 + g \bar{\psi} \phi \psi , $$

where $\mathcal{L}_{\psi}$ is the Dirac Lagrangian and $\phi$ is the scalar field. Then, the generating functional $Z$ of the full theory is given by

$Z = \int \mathcal{D} \bar{\psi}\mathcal{D}\psi \mathcal{D}\phi \exp \Big[i \Big(\int d^4x \mathcal{L}_{\psi} - \int d^4 x  \frac{1}{2} \phi 
(\square  + m^2) \phi + g \bar{\psi} \phi \psi \Big) \Big] = \\
 = \int \mathcal{D} \bar{\psi}\mathcal{D}\psi \exp \Big[i \int d^4x \mathcal{L}_{\psi} \Big] \int \mathcal{D}\phi \exp[\frac{i}{2} \int d^4x \phi 
(\square  + m^2) \phi + 2g \bar{\psi}  \psi \phi] $.

In the book of Lancaster & Blundell (Quantum Field Theory for the Gifted Amateur) we find the solution for a free scalar, which is

$Z_{scalar} = C \exp \Big[ - \frac{1}{2} \int d^4x d^4y J(x) [i A^{-1}(x,y)J(y)] \Big]$,

where $J$ are "sources", $A^{-1}(x,y)$ is the "inverse" of $- (\square + m^2)$ and $C$ is a (divergent) constant. If I consider $J(x) \equiv \bar{\psi}(x)\psi(x)$ in the Yukawa potential, I obtain

$Z = C \int \mathcal{D} \bar{\psi}\mathcal{D}\psi  \exp \Big[i \Big(\int d^4x \mathcal{L}_{\psi} (x) + \int d^4x d^4 y  \bar{\psi}(x)\psi(x) A^{-1}(x,y) \bar{\psi}(y)\psi(y) \big]$

and I am interpreting $\int d^4y \bar{\psi}(x)\psi(x) A^{-1}(x,y) \bar{\psi}(y)\psi(y)$ as an effective interaction between two fermions. Is it right? Why?  If it is right, can I always do it for any quadratic Lagrangian? For instance, in the electromagnetic coupling?

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, in the path integral one can in principle integrate out a field that only appears quadratically in the action via a Gaussian integration. However, the reduced theory is non-local, and there might be an issue with zero-modes.
2. As an example of integrating out the EM field, see e.g [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/547254/2451) Phys.SE post.