# D'Alembertian of a delta-function of a space-time interval (i.e. on the light-cone)

Tags: special-relativity, mathematical-physics, differentiation, greens-functions, dirac-delta-distributions

How one differentiates a delta-function of a space-time interval? Namely,
$$[\partial_t^2 - \partial_x^2 - \partial_y^2 - \partial_z^2] \, \delta(t^2-x^2-y^2-z^2) \, .$$
Somewhere I saw that the result was $$4\pi\delta^{4}(x).$$ However, have no idea on how to obtain it.

Comment: Crossposted from https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4020334/11127

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the theory of [generalized functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_function), let us regularize the [Dirac delta distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function)$^1$
$$ \delta(x^2)~=~\lim_{\varepsilon\searrow 0^+}\delta_{\varepsilon}(x^2), \qquad x^2~:=~x^{\mu}\eta_{\mu\nu}x^{\nu}, \tag{1}$$
via a smooth $C^{\infty}$-function$^2$
$$ \delta_{\varepsilon}(x^2)
~=~ \frac{1}{\pi}\frac{\varepsilon}{(x^2)^2+\varepsilon^2} 
~=~-\frac{1}{\pi}{\rm Im} \frac{1}{x^2+i\varepsilon}, \qquad \varepsilon~>~0. \tag{2}$$
Eqs. (1)-(2) are a well-known [representation of the Dirac delta distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#Representations_of_the_delta_function).

It is now mathematically well-defined to apply the d'Alembert operator on the smooth function (2). We calculate:
$$  \partial_{\mu}\delta_{\varepsilon}(x^2)~=~\frac{1}{\pi}{\rm Im} \frac{2x_{\mu}}{(x^2+i\varepsilon)^2},\tag{3}$$
$$  \partial_{\mu}\partial_{\nu}\delta_{\varepsilon}(x^2)
~=~\frac{1}{\pi}{\rm Im} \left(\frac{2\eta_{\mu\nu}}{(x^2+i\varepsilon)^2}-\frac{8x_{\mu}x_{\nu}}{(x^2+i\varepsilon)^3}\right),\tag{4}$$
$$\begin{align}  \Box \delta_{\varepsilon}(x^2)~=~&\frac{1}{\pi}{\rm Im} \left(\frac{8}{(x^2+i\varepsilon)^2}-\frac{8x^2}{(x^2+i\varepsilon)^3}\right) \cr
~=~&\frac{1}{\pi}{\rm Im}\frac{8i\varepsilon}{(x^2+i\varepsilon)^3}\cr
~\longrightarrow~& -4\pi  \delta^4(x) 
\qquad \mathrm{for} \qquad \varepsilon ~\searrow~ 0^+.
\end{align}\tag{5}$$

Eq. (5) implies OP's sought-for proposition.

> *Proposition.*
> $$ \Box \delta (x^2)~=~-4\pi  \delta^4(x).\tag{6}$$

*Sketched proof of the last line in eq. (5).* Consider a test function $f\in C^{\infty}_c(\mathbb{R}^4)$, i.e., an infinitely often differentiable function $f$ with compact support. Then

$$\begin{align}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^4}\! \mathrm{d}^4x & ~ f(x)~ \Box \delta_{\varepsilon}(x^2) \cr
~\stackrel{x=\sqrt{\varepsilon} y}{=}~& 
\int_{\mathbb{R}^4}\!\frac{\mathrm{d}^4y}{\pi} ~ f(\sqrt{\varepsilon} y)~{\rm Im}\frac{8i}{(y^2+i)^3}\cr  
~\longrightarrow~&  f(0) \int_{\mathbb{R}^4}\!\frac{\mathrm{d}^4y}{\pi} ~ {\rm Im}\frac{8i}{(y^2+i)^3}\cr
~\stackrel{y=(t,\vec{r})}{=}~&~ 4 f(0) {\rm Im} \int_{\mathbb{R}_+}\!r^2\mathrm{d}r \int_{\mathbb{R}}\!\mathrm{d}t \frac{8i}{(r^2-t^2+i)^3}\cr
~\stackrel{a:=\sqrt{r^2+i}}{=}&~ 4 f(0) {\rm Im} \int_{\mathbb{R}_+}\!r^2\mathrm{d}r \int_{\mathbb{R}}\!\mathrm{d}t \left(\frac{2i}{t^2-a^2}\right)^3\cr
~=~~~& 4 f(0) {\rm Im} \int_{\mathbb{R}_+}\!r^2\mathrm{d}r \frac{-i}{a^3}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\!\mathrm{d}t \left(\frac{1}{t-a}-\frac{1}{t+a}\right)^3\cr
~\stackrel{\text{residue thm.}}{=}&~ 4 f(0) {\rm Im} \int_{\mathbb{R}_+}\!r^2\mathrm{d}r \frac{-i}{a^3} 2\pi i \cr
&\qquad \left(0+\left.\frac{3}{(t+a)^2}\right|_{t=a}+\left.\frac{3}{(t-a)^2}\right|_{t=-a}+0\right)\cr
~=~~~& 12\pi f(0) {\rm Im} \int_{\mathbb{R}_+}\!r^2\mathrm{d}r \frac{1}{a^5} \cr
~=~~~& 12\pi f(0) {\rm Im} \int_{\mathbb{R}_+}\!\frac{r^2\mathrm{d}r}{(r^2+i)^{5/2}} \cr
~=~~~& 12\pi f(0) {\rm Im} \left[\frac{r^3}{3i(r^2+i)^{3/2}}\right]^{r=\infty}_{r=0} \cr
~=~~~& -4\pi f(0)   \qquad \mathrm{for} \qquad \varepsilon ~\searrow~ 0^+,
\end{align}\tag{7}$$

because of, e.g., [Lebesgue's dominated convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem). Here we have implicitly assumed that $a:=\sqrt{r^2+i}$ is the square root branch in the upper complex plane. $\Box$

--

$^1$ In this answer we work in units where the speed-of-light $c=1$ is one, and we use the Minkowski sign convention $(−,+,+,+)$.

$^2$ The $i\varepsilon$-prescription has an interpretation in terms of [Wick rotation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wick_rotation), cf. e.g. my Math.SE answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3908388/11127).

Comment: Notes for later: $\quad {\rm sgn}_{\eta}(t)=\frac{2}{\pi}\arctan\frac{t}{\eta}$. $\quad \theta_{\eta}(t)=\frac{1}{\pi}{\arg}(-t+i\eta)=\frac{1}{\pi}{\rm arccot}\frac{-t}{\eta}$. $\quad\delta_{\eta}(t)=\frac{1}{\pi}{\rm Im}\frac{1}{t-i\eta}$. $\quad \delta^{\prime}_{\eta}(t)=-\frac{1}{\pi}{\rm Im}\frac{1}{(t-i\eta)^2}$. Retarded Greens function $\quad G_{\rm ret}(x)=2\theta(t)\frac{\delta(x^2)}{4\pi}=\frac{\delta(t-r)}{4\pi r}$. Regularization: $\quad 4\pi G_{{\rm ret},\eta,\varepsilon}(x)=2\theta_{\eta}(t)\delta_{\varepsilon}(x^2)$. Here $\eta \sim \sqrt{\varepsilon}$ but that's not necessary.

Comment: $\quad\Box 4\pi G_{\rm ret}(x) =2\theta(t)\Box\delta(x^2) +4\delta(t)\partial_t\delta(x^2) +2\delta^{\prime}(t)\delta(x^2)$. All terms localize at the origin of spacetime. Terms odd in $t$ vanishes, which are almost all. $\quad 4\pi\partial_tG_{\rm ret}(\vec{r},0) =2\delta(0)\delta(r^2) =\frac{2}{\pi^2\eta}{\rm Im}\frac{1}{r^2-i\varepsilon} \stackrel{?}{=}4\pi \delta^3(\vec{r})$. $\quad \delta_{\varepsilon}^3(\vec{r}) =\frac{1}{\pi^2\sqrt{2\varepsilon}}{\rm Im}\frac{1}{r^2-i\varepsilon} =\frac{\sqrt{\varepsilon/2}}{\pi^2}\frac{1}{r^4+\varepsilon^2}$. $\Rightarrow \pi\eta=\sqrt{\varepsilon/2}$.

Answer (score 2):

The action of any distributional "function" such as a delta function is really only determined when you integrate it with a test function;  and two distributions are equal if and only if their actions agree on all test functions.  So let's see what this distribution does when we integrate it with a smooth test function $f(t, \vec{r})$.

We start with the integral
$$
I[f] = \iiiint d^4 x \, \left[ f(t, \vec{r}) \Box  \delta(\Delta s^2) \right]
$$
where $\Box$ stands for the wave operator under the metric convention $(+ - - \, -)$.  Integrating by parts twice and assuming that $f$ has compact support (as all good test functions should), this becomes
$$
I[f] = \iiiint dt d^3\vec{r} \, \left[ (\Box f)  \delta(t^2 - x^2 - y^2 - z^2) \right]
$$
We can then use the rules concerning composition of the delta-function with a function to rewrite this as
$$
I[f] = \iiiint dt d^3\vec{r} \, (\Box f) \left[ \frac{\delta(t - |\vec{r}|)}{2 |t|} + \frac{\delta(t + |\vec{r}|)}{2 |t|} \right].
$$
Finally, we can integrate over $t$ to obtain
$$
I[f] = \iiint d^3 \vec{r} \, \frac{ \Box f(|\vec{r}|, \vec{r}) + \Box f(-|\vec{r}|, \vec{r})}{2 |\vec{r}|}.
$$
The notation here for $\Box f(\pm|\vec{r}|, \vec{r})$ is awkward, but it means "$\Box f$ evaluated at $t = \pm|\vec{r}|$."

This action will differ from the action of the distribution $4 \pi \delta^4(x^\mu)$.  In particular, we have
$$
J[f] = \iiiint d^4 x \, f(t,\vec{r}) \left[ 4 \pi \delta^4(x^\mu) \right] = 4 \pi f(0, \vec{0}).
$$
$I$ and $J$ are only equal if their results agree on all test functions $f$.  But if we choose a test function that vanishes at the origin and for which $\Box f$ is positive on some portion of the light cone, then $I$ and $J$ will yield a positive result and a zero result respectively.  Thus, the distributions are not equal.

It is possible that the actions of these two distributions will be equal on test functions $f$ that have special properties (for example, if $f$ is the Green's function for the wave operator or something like that.)  This may be all that is necessary in a particular context.  But the two distributions are not equal in a strict sense.

Comment: There is a problem (singularity) at the $x^\mu = 0$. We can use expressions such as $\delta (x^2-a^2) = \frac{1}{2 |x|} [ \delta (x-a) + \delta (x+a)]$ only when $|x| \neq 0$ which is false for $a=0$. In our case it should somehow give rise to $4\pi \delta^4(x)$.

Comment: Speaking of $\Box \delta(t^2-x^2-y^2-z^2)$... It is easy to show using $s \delta(s) = 0$ that $\frac{d^2}{d s^2}\delta(s) = \frac{2}{s^2} \delta(s)$. This would give us $\Box \delta(t^2-x^2-y^2-z^2) = 0$ after some manipulations. However, it should be $4 \pi \delta^{4} (x)$ somehow, due to the $x^\mu = 0$ additional singularity.