# Check of the Green function for the Klein-Gordon equation

Tags: differential-equations, greens-functions, propagator, klein-gordon-equation

In order to derive the Green function for the Klein-Gordon equation, one considers
$$
\Box G(x-x')+m^2G(x-x')=\delta^4(x-x')
$$
where $\delta^4(x)=\delta(x_0)\delta(x_1)\delta(x_2)\delta(x_4)$. The widely known solution (e.g. see [propagator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagator)) will depend on distributions like
$$
\Theta(x_0^2-x_1^2-x_2^2-x_3^2), \qquad \delta(x_0^2-x_1^2-x_2^2-x_3^2).
$$
Therefore, if I substitute the solution back into the equation, it is difficult to see how to recover the more standard $\delta^4(x)$. On the other side, in momentum space, we know how to move from $d^4p$ to $d^3p/(2E)$ and keeping Lorentz invariance. What is the further condition in place for this case?

The rationale behind this question is, given an exact solution of the homogeneous equation, how I could get the Green function? Indeed, it is easy to check that the function $J_1(m x)/x$ is a solution of the homogeneous Klein-Gordon equation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose we have a solution to the K.G. equation $(\Box^{2}_{x}+m^{2})\phi(x)=0$. Consider the Feynman Propagator $\Delta_{F}(x-y) = \langle 0|T\{\phi(x)\phi(y)\}|0\rangle$, where the fields are time ordered. We can show that this is the Greens function for the K.G. operator by first noting that:
\begin{equation}
\partial_{x_{0}}\langle 0|T\{\phi(x)\phi(y)\}|0\rangle\overset{!}{=}\partial_{x_{0}}\langle 0|\theta(x_{0}-y_{0})\phi(x)\phi(y)+\theta(y_{0}-x_{0})\phi(y)\phi(x)|0\rangle = \langle 0|\delta(x_{0}-y_{0})\phi(x)\phi(y)+\theta(x_{0}-y_{0})\partial_{x_{0}}\phi(x)\phi(y)-\delta(y_{0}-x_{0})\phi(y)\phi(x)+\theta(y_{0}-x_{0})\phi(y)\partial_{x_{0}}\phi(x)|0\rangle
= \langle 0|\theta(x_{0}-y_{0})\partial_{x_{0}}\phi(x)\phi(y)+\theta(y_{0}-x_{0})\phi(y)\partial_{x_{0}}\phi(x)|0\rangle
= \langle 0|T\{\partial_{x_{0}}\phi(x)\phi(y)\}|0\rangle
\end{equation}
Repeating this again but taking note that $\Pi(x) = \partial_{x_0}\phi(x)$:
\begin{equation}
\partial_{x_{0}}\langle 0|T\{\partial_{x_{0}}\phi(x)\phi(y)\}|0\rangle = \langle 0|T\{\partial_{x_{0}}^{2}\phi(x)\phi(y)\}|0\rangle - [\Pi(x),\phi(y)]\delta(x_{0}-y_{0}) 
\\= \langle 0|T\{\partial_{x_{0}}^{2}\phi(x)\phi(y)\}|0\rangle - (2\pi)^{3}i\delta^{(3)}(x-y)\delta(x_{0}-y_{0}) = \langle 0|T\{\partial_{x_{0}}^{2}\phi(x)\phi(y)\}|0\rangle - (2\pi)^{3}i\delta^{(4)}(x^{\mu}-y^{\mu})
\end{equation}
The spacial derivative part of the K.G. operator commutes with time ordering so we get that:
\begin{equation}
(\Box^{2}_{x}+m^{2})\langle 0|T\{\phi(x)\phi(y)\}|0\rangle 
\\= \langle 0|T\{\Box^{2}_{x}\phi(x)\phi(y)\}|0\rangle  - ((2\pi)^{3}i\delta^{(4)}(x^{\mu}-y^{\mu})+m^{2})\langle 0|T\{\phi(x)\phi(y)\}|0\rangle
\end{equation}
But as $\phi(x)$ is a solution to K.G. we can then say that $\langle 0|T\{\Box^{2}_{x}\phi(x)\phi(y)\}|0\rangle = -m^{2}\langle 0|T\{\phi(x)\phi(y)\}|0\rangle$. Hence:
\begin{equation}
(\Box_{x}^2+m^{2})\Delta_{F}(x-y) = -i(2\pi)^{3}\delta^{(4)}(x^{\mu}-y^{\mu})
\end{equation}
as required up to some normalisation factor.

Comment: Neat reply, thanks. Any hint about the first part of my question?

Comment: Found at https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/614754/.